# How to send special characters in ajax request in EXTJS

Tags: java, ajax, extjs

I have simple `extjs(2.0)` form and it contains dynamically generated textfields. I am sending the form parameters to `servlet` using `ajax request`. If i enter any `special characters` in textfield, the textfield values are coming as `URL escape codes`. 
For Example `&` is represented with `%26` in servlet.

Instead of using ajax request if i use form submit, it is working. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you clarify what your question is? it's unclear, tempting -1. Some example of correct and uncorrect case maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Encode values to JSON before sending, and decode them on server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the parameters to 'GET' method then use url encoding and send.

Try looking into [encodeURI()](http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode/) and [decodeURI()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp).

If you are using 'POST' method then normal sending only it works.

Comment: Raju it would be helpfull if you paste a sample code which is not working... So that we can debug and fix.